# vb.net 2010 Synchronize two access databases

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I'm writing a desktop application that uses the main access database that will be hosted on a central server, but there will be a laptop with the app on that has an offline mode so records can be created offsite. When the laptop returns I want it needs to be synced back to the main database.

Has anybody got any pointers on a way to do this, I've briefly read about JRO but is there an alternative / better method?

Originally, I was just going to write some custom code to do this, but thought I'd check to make sure there wasn't something already out there.

Comment: Duplicate of a question on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/292272/how-do-i-synchronize-multiple-access-databases-together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jet Replication is a perfect solution for this kind of scenario, because you can use the simplest form of it, Direct Replication, and don't need to have any outside dependencies.

Assuming your server is named \HomeOffice\ and the database is named "MainDatabase.mdb" and is stored in the \AccessDatabases\ folder, you could use this code behind a command button to synchronize from the laptop to the server:

```
  Dim dbServer as DAO.Database

  Set dbServer = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("\\HomeOffice\AccessDatabases\MainDatabase.mdb")
  dbServer.Synchronize CurrentDB.Name
  dbServer.Close
  Set dbServer = Nothing
```

Now, there's no error handling, and you haven't checked for conflicts, so you'd need to do more than that, but that would get you started with the basics.

See the [Jet Replication Wiki](http://dfenton.com/DFA/Replication/) for lots more information on Jet Replication.

Comment: Turns out I'm actually trying to do something else - but If I was going down the sync route, I like the sound of your answer- thanks for the input!

Comment: I did miss the vb.net aspect -- you'd like use JRO instead of DAO (as my code does), but it's almost identical code.

Answer (score 3):

Access (at least through 2003) has built in capabilities to replicate a database that would be far better to use than rolling your own.

Here's some documentation on that feature: [Database Replication](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/CH006252684.aspx)

Comment: Jet Replication is supported in all versions of Access starting with A95, as long as you limit yourself to MDB format. It is only ACCDB format that lacks support for Jet Replication.

Answer (score 0):

MS Sync Framework could be the answer, but it's a bit tricky to set up... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/bb902854.aspx) that is compatible with ADO.NET and MS SQL Server / SQL Server Compact, but that's not a small component, more like a multi-component framework.